# How to style a typeahead in a nav in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code looks like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    <style type="text/css">
    


/*.tt-query,  UPDATE: newer versions use tt-input instead of tt-query */
.tt-hint {
    width: 396px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 8px;
    outline: none;
}

/*.tt-query { /* UPDATE: newer versions use tt-input instead of tt-query 
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
*/
.tt-hint {
    color: #999;
}

.tt-menu { /* UPDATE: newer versions use tt-menu instead of tt-dropdown-menu */
    width: 422px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.tt-suggestion {
    padding: 3px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor { /* UPDATE: newer versions use .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor */
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0097cf;

}

.tt-suggestion p {
    margin: 0;
}
    </style>
     </head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <input id = "pages" class = "typeahead form-controler" type="text" placeholder="abc">
          </li> 
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </a>
          </li> 
        </ul>
        
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
   <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var pages = ['abc',' def','ghi'];
/***************************/
/*I'm discussing the following comment*/
/***************************/
/*
$('#pages.typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'pages',
  source: substringMatcher(pages)
});*/
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

(note, it doesn't run here due to me not being able to include the bootstrap and typeahead js).

When I leave the last part of the Javascript disabled, the typeahead is styled properly:

(I can't include a picture, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpHTQ.png for a screenshot

On the other hand, when I uncomment the last part of Javascript (to make typeahead work), it's not styled:

See https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW3yd.png for a screenshot

**UPDATE**

Removed extra style from the top and changed to `$('#pages').typeahead({`

Now the screenshot looks like http :// i.stack.imgur.com/isJPh.png

There's a textbox under a textbox. The bottom one is not editable, is styled and the suggestions appear there. The top one is where the typing happens, is not styled and has final text appears there.

Comment: You've  got an extra `style` on line 11

Comment: I found that it works if I set hint to false. Now how to fix that problem ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `.typeahead` defined in your CSS. Here's an example:

```js
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
}, {
  name: 'states',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```

```css
/**Custom**/

.navbar.navbar-custom {
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-custom .formSearch {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.navbar-custom .form-control,
.navbar-custom .form-control:hover,
.navbar-custom .form-control:focus {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.navbar-custom .inner-addon {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-custom .inner-addon .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 7px;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #444;
}
.navbar-custom .right-addon .glyphicon {
  right: 10px;
}
.navbar-custom .right-addon input {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle,
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:focus {
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
/*Typeahead*/

.navbar-custom .typeahead,
.navbar-custom .tt-query,
.navbar-custom .tt-hint {
  width: 396px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.navbar-custom .typeahead {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-custom .typeahead:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0097cf;
}
.navbar-custom .tt-query {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
.navbar-custom .tt-hint {
  color: #999
}
.navbar-custom .tt-menu {
  width: 396px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.navbar-custom .tt-suggestion {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.navbar-custom .tt-suggestion:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;
}
.navbar-custom .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;
}
.navbar-custom .tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-custom .formSearch,
  .navbar-custom .form-control,
  .navbar-custom .tt-menu {
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 250px;
  }
  .navbar-custom .right-addon .glyphicon {
    right: 0;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-collapse {
    background: #f5f5f5;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <form class="formSearch" role="search">
        <div class="inner-addon right-addon"> <span id="the-basics">
                    <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" id="the-basics"placeholder="United States"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the css.

You need to play with the default values to adapt them to your style.

Also, for future snippets in SO, keep html, js y css separated. Ensure that everything is working as in your system. When not, ensure that the references to external libraries are correct.

To include [bootstrap](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js) and [typeahead](http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.min.js) *js* files use their CDNs.

I leave you a snippet that is working and styling the search box nicely (try it in "full page" mode):

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
    return function findMatches(q, cb) {
      var matches, substringRegex;

      // an array that will be populated with substring matches
      matches = [];

      // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
      substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

      // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
      // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
      $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
        if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
          matches.push(str);
        }
      });

      cb(matches);
    };
  };

  var pages = ['abb', 'abc', 'acb', 'acc', 'def', 'ghi'];
  /***************************/
  /*I'm discussing the following comment*/
  /***************************/
  
  $('#pages.typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'pages',
    source: substringMatcher(pages)
  });

});
```

```css
#myNavbar.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
.navbar-nav > li{
  float:left;
        margin-left: 10px;
 }


.typeahead,
.tt-query,
.tt-hint {
  width: 396px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
     -moz-border-radius: 8px;
          border-radius: 8px;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.typeahead {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.typeahead:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0097cf;
}

.tt-query {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.tt-hint {
  color: #999
}

.tt-menu {
  width: 422px;
  margin: 12px 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
     -moz-border-radius: 8px;
          border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
          box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.tt-suggestion {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.tt-suggestion:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;
}

.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;

}

.tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Test</title>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- typeahead -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <input id="pages" class="typeahead form-controler" type="text" placeholder="abc">
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>


      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps!

**UPDATE**:

Beyond this point, if you need further customization of the *typeahead's* look, you just need to deal with normal CSS.

For example, as you said on your comments, the `glyphicon-search` is getting cover while typing. That is normal CSS. You can see (using a web inspector) that `.navbar-nav > li` elements have a media query that make them float in a big screen, and the issue happens just in small ones. You just need to add the same CSS but without any media query to have a consistent behavior:

```
.navbar-nav > li{
    float:left;
}
```

And to fix the popping up thingy, allow elements to overflow the *navbar*:

```
#myNavbar.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

I have updated the snippet.

Comment: try typing something into the textbox. The typeahead is hidden

Comment: @joeshmoe: I tried it before posting it :) It is working for my on Firefox 40.0.3, Chrome 45.0.2454.85 m, IE 11.0.9600.18036, Safari 5.1.7 and Opera 31.0. Which browser/version are you using? What do you mean by hidden?

Comment: http://imgur.com/mcZLaia If you notice, the bottom of the typeahead hint (this is even worse if there is more than one hint) is hidden, and you need to scroll to see it. Same result on Firefox/Chrome/Android.

Comment: So you meant the `glyphicon-search` icon. When somebody is helping you (even when the question is supposed to be already answered), you should try to be as specific as possible. The second comment is specific, the first one ("typeahead is hidden") not at all. I have updated my answer.

Comment: no. I mean that the hints popping up. Did you see how "def" looks? btw, I would have +1 you, I just don't have the rep

Comment: or, to make it clearer, see http://imgur.com/Q4PyHYe . I'm not worried about the icon. I'm worried that the ghi "hint" is partially hidden (and had there been another hint (say ghik) it would be invisible.

Comment: Ok, understood. Have a look now to the new update. I also added more items started with "a" to try it out.